# HTML5 (& CSS3?) Create a grid of squares in the background

Tags: html, css

I had an idea for a background but I don't know if it can be done, and if it can, what the best method would be. Just to let you into my idea, it's a grid of squares as the background for a page but when you mouse over one it changes color and slowly shifts back(I know how to do the animation portion). The grid is supposed to span the entire page, width and height, and overflow would be hidden. I'd also wish that it could re size itself if the page does

So I'm wondering if this can be done. If it can, how would I generate the grid?

I'm at a complete loss. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `<canvas>`. Or maybe fill entire body with equally sized DIV's with height and width defined in percentages. Lets say that would be grid of 10x10 DIV's. Or you can create on -the-fly with jQuery as many DIV as you want (to fill whole height). You can float those DIV's to fill entire viewport, and if window is resized use media queries to arrange them. On hover, you can apply some animation on every DIV. Of course, you can put other elements over those DIV's.

Comment: Interesting... I'll take a look at `<canvas>`. Looks very promising. I could use javascript to fill a div already in place with a negative z-index, using simple for loops. If I detect the resize, maybe I could recall the function.... Lots of potential. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm. I used javascript to deploy them using a nested for loop. I was able to make the animation easy by using css and `:hover`. Thanks man!

Comment: @user1191196 That's great! Sincerely, I was never thought about this kind of background (clients never asked for that), but now I'm sure I will use it on some site :)

Comment: just an FYI for anyone reading: an issue I noticed, was that the line-height attribute becomes an issue and should be set to 0. otherwise you get an annoying gap between lines. ANOTHER issue that I haven't solved, is that if it is behind ANY element, the padding(i think it's padding) will not allow the :hover aspect to take affect if it is in the way.